# javascript - How many elements with a certain tag name I have

Tags: javascript

Say in my body I have this:

```
<body onLoad="h2_num();">
<h2>Hello world!</h2>
<b>Say hello!</b>
<h1>Hey!</h1>
<h2>My HTML page is</h2>
awesome.
<h2>The End</h2>
```

I want to create a function `h2_num()` that will return the number of `<h2>`s there are in the body (in other words it will return 3). How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function h2_num() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('h2').length;
}
```

Edit: as RGraham mentions, this is slower than `getElementsByTagName`, but it has the advantage that if you needed to find `H2`s inside another element, you can do this very easily with `querySelectorAll`. For example, finding `H2`s in an element with `class="moose"`

```
function h2InClassMoose_num() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('.moose h2').length;
}
```

Comment: Beware. This is much slower than `getElementsByTagName`, at least for me in Chrome 33/Windows7 - http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbytagname

Comment: @RGraham, well, I couldn't very well copy what everyone else had done, could I :) Looking at the jsperf: wow! I didn't realise it was that much slower. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Ha, I know what you mean! Tbh I would have went this way if I was writing it.

Answer (score 2):

The below will give you the result:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h2').length
```

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns "Node list". It is similar to an array and you can the count of the elements using the `length` attribute.

```
function h2_num () {
    var count = document.getElementsByTagName('h2').length;
    return count;
}
```

If you won't do anything with the `count` variable, you can just use

```
function h2_num () {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('h2').length;
}
```

Comment: `var count = document.getElementsByTagName('h2').length;`

Comment: Yes, I changed my answer.

Comment: Why are you using `getElementsByClassName`? That will not work.